# How to get the data for my controller when http request in progress?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have following controller

1) **introCtrl**

**2) ArticleCtrl**

**3) articleService (Service)**

Now  I am sending an http request from introCrtl

```
 .controller('IntroCtrl', function($scope, articleService) {
     articleService.getArticles();
});
```

and  AricleCtrl is

```
  .controller('ArticleCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,articleService) {
   $scope.articles = articleService.fetchArticles();
})
```

and my Service is

```
.service('articleService', function ($http, $q) {

var articleList = [];
        var getArticles = function() {
                $http({
                    url: "muylink,co,",
                    data: { starLimit: 0, endLimit: 150,created_date: 0 },
                    method: 'POST',
                    withCredentials: true,
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    articleList.push(data);

                }).error(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                })
            };

        var fetchArticles = function() {
                return articleList[0];
            }

            return {
                getArticles: getArticles,
                fetchArticles: fetchArticles
            };



});
```

Which is also working fine. Now Problem is that

Sometimes  my http request sending **respone** late and i got nothing  in

**$scope.articles**.

Can we implement watch here.  How i need to implement $watch here. I dont want to implement promise. because i want to run http request behind the scene.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you switch to a state based setup with ui-router that way you can do this :

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
      url: 'the/url/you/want',
      resolve:{
         articleService: 'articleService' // you are dependency injecting it here,
         articles: function (articleService) {
             return articleService.getArticles.$promise;
         } 
      },
       controller: 'IntroCtrl'
   })

// then your controller can just inject the articles and they will be resolved before your controller loads so you it will always be fetched prior

.controller('IntroCtrl', function($scope, articles) {
     $scope.articles = articles;
});
```

for more information take a look at this

[ui-router info](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

Comment: I would definitely not recommend it. A best practice is when you can avoid using watchers then avoid them. Thats because when you overuse them you are putting a burden on the angular digest cycle. and as soon as you hit around 2000 watchers on a single page you will start noticing a significant performance decrease.

Comment: check out point 7 on  https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/top-10-mistakes-angularjs-developers-make

Answer (score 0):

All to do is set watch on articleList and provide maintaining function. 
As you are watching array, it's good to change it to string.

Create function in watch which results array.

```
$scope.$watch( function() { 
return JSON.stringify($scope.articleList); 
}, function(newVal,oldVal){ 
//provide logic here 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your service result is asynchron (like http requests) you should return promises from your service.

```
.controller('ArticleCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,articleService) {
   articleService.fetchArticles().then(function(articles) {
      $scope.articles = articles;
   });
})
```

Service

```
// not sure about your service logic... simplified:
.service('articleService', function ($http, $q) {

    var articleListPromise ;
    var getArticles = function() {
            articleListPromise = $http(/* ...*/);
    };

    var fetchArticles = function() {
        return articleListPromise.then(function(data) {
           return data[0];
        });
    }

    return {
       getArticles: getArticles,
       fetchArticles: fetchArticles
    };
```

});